# TCP Tweaking options and Results: Any suggestions?

Tags: networking, tcp

I first tried with the default windows XP TCP option(It doesn't have TCPWindowSize option and TCP1323 in its Registry setting). I dynamically set those options using TCP optimizer. Here I list out the result with and without TCP Tweaking option.

I see no major improvements in TCP after increasing window size optimally too.

What value should I set to increase the performance?

> Results:
>
> Without any window size and MTU
>   setting from server to client
>   (receiving)
>
> TCPWindowSize :
>
> MTU :
>
> TTL:
>
> Size:586 MB
>
> total duration : 03:47
>
> With window size extension from server
>   to client (receiving)
>
> Bandwidth :100 Mbps
>
> Latency: 100ms
>
> BDP :1250000
>
> TCPWindowSize : 1250000
>
> MTU :1500
>
> TTL:128
>
> Size:586MB
>
> total duration : 03:44
>
> With window size extension from server
>   to client (receiving)
>
> TCPWindowSize :64240
>
> MTU :1500
>
> TTL :112
>
> Size: 586MB
>
> total duration : 03:49

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506804/tcp-tweaking-and-tuning), it explains why you probably shouldn't try to optimize the TCP stack. Your bottleneck is probably somewhere else (slow hard disks perhaps?)

Comment: The link in this answer refers to a page that has been removed.